# Getting malloc() mismatching next->prev_size when trying to format a string like argv

Tags: c

I have a main program where I read stdin into a buffer using open_memstream.  Now I am attempting to structure the string to be like argv.

```
char **cli_argv;
char *buf;
size_t len;

void get_args() {
    int c;
    int c_count = 0;
    cli_argc = 0;
    char args[100];

    /* transfer buffer contents to a string, replacing whitespace and determine length */

    FILE *captured = fmemopen(buf,len,"r");

    if (captured == NULL) {
        debug("unable to fmemopen");
    } else {
        while ((c=fgetc(captured)) != EOF) {
            if (!isspace(c)) {
                args[c_count] = c;
            } else {
                args[c_count] = '\0';
                cli_argc++;
            }

            c_count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(captured);
    stop_input_stream();
    success("transfered contents of buf to string");

    /* find sizes of words and malloc enough memory */
    int arg_sizes[cli_argc];
    int argc_size = 0;
    int argc_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c_count; i++) {
        if (args[i] != '\0') {
            argc_size++;
        } else {
            arg_sizes[argc_index] = argc_size + 1;
            argc_index++;
            argc_size = 0;
        }
    }

    cli_argv = malloc(cli_argc * sizeof(char));
    *cli_argv = args;

    for (int i = 0; i < cli_argc; i++) {
        cli_argv[i] = malloc(arg_sizes[i] * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cli_argc; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",cli_argv[i]);
    }

}
```

However, this code is giving me a malloc error:

[image]

I trying changing cliargc * sizeof((char)) to ccount*sizeof((char), thinking that I malloc'd too little.  but unfortunately that did not make the error disappear.  Also, I'm not sure how to set cli_argv[i] as a proper pointer.  Can someone help?  TIA.

Comment: `cli_argv = malloc(cli_argc * sizeof(char));` Use `cli_argv = malloc(cli_argc * sizeof *cli_argv);` instead. You ask for `sizeof char` when you need `sizeof char *`.. May be more, but this one is obvious.

Comment: I made the change, but received the same error from malloc.

Comment: The error message almost certainly means you've trampled outside the bounds of a piece of allocated memory and modified control information that should not have been modified.  Ideally, you'd use [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) or `-fsanitize=address` or something similar to track the problem down.

Comment: Your code is not compilable — the line `FILE *captured = fmemopen(buf,len,"r");` references `buf` and `len`, neither of which is defined at that point in the code you've shown.  You say `cli_argv` is a global variable — but what is it declared like?  Is it `char **cli_argv;` or something else?  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).

Comment: I apologize I should have said, buf and len are global as well and are the values used in open_memstream.  I declared it as char **cli_argv.

Comment: Your array `args` is very small — many command lines are a lot longer than 100 characters.  Also, why not simply use `strdup()` to duplicate the input buffer and parse that, instead of fiddling around with the memory stream.  How does your code handle leading blanks, multiple blanks between arguments, trailing blanks?  You assign a local variable to a global variable — `*cli_argv = args;` — which means the pointer is invalid as soon as your function returns.

Comment: thank you @JonathanLeffler.  I figured out that i freed buf before I closed input_stream in my stop_input_stream function, leading to the malloc error.  The reason I am using a memory stream is because this stream is only written to when SIGIO is received, however, cannot guarantee that we have a complete line of input before receiving another SIGIO, so the professor suggested using open_memstream.

Comment: If you're mixing signal handling with all this, you're in for a world of hurt.  Standard C is impossibly restrictive on what you can do in a signal handler.  POSIX is a lot more generous, but there are still lots of limitations — and a key one is that signal handlers cannot reliably call functions that dynamically allocate memory.  I'm not sure how that's all working for you — I've never experimented with SIGIO so I'm not sure how you might be using it (and I've not used memory streams either — there's never been a good enough reason to do so).

Comment: I made sure that my handlers only set flags and that any functions called to act on the input are in the main loop after checking for the flag and the file descriptor that called it.  Additionally, the signals are set to come in asynchronously and in a non-blocking fashion.  Thank you for advising though, I did not realize that handlers cannot call functions that malloc reliably.

Comment: Any thoughts on the second question of how I can make cli_argv[i] point to the correct strings?  I tried printing them with the code as is, and the values are just garbage.  I appreciate all the input so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring issues with signal handling (because, AFAICT from the comments, the argument parsing will not happen in a signal handler), this is what I'd use:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char **argv;    /* Null-terminated vector of argument strings */
    char  *argb;    /* Data that elements of argv point to */
    size_t argc;    /* Number of arguments */
    /* av.argv[av.argc] == 0 */
} ArgVector;

static ArgVector make_argv(const char *buffer)
{
    ArgVector av =
    {
        /* At worst, there is one argument for every two characters */
        .argv = calloc(sizeof(av.argv[0]), (strlen(buffer) + 1) / 2 + 1),
        .argb = strdup(buffer),
        .argc = 0
    };

    if (av.argv == 0 || av.argb == 0)
    {
        free(av.argv);
        free(av.argb);
        av.argv = 0;
        av.argb = 0;
        return av;
    }

    char *s = av.argb;
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        char c;
        while ((c = *s) != '\0' && isspace((unsigned char)c))
            s++;
        if (c != '\0')
        {
            av.argv[av.argc++] = s;
            while ((c = *s) != '\0' && !isspace((unsigned char)c))
                s++;
            if (c != '\0')
                *s++ = '\0';
        }
    }
    
    return av;
}

static void free_argv(ArgVector *av)
{
    if (av != 0)
    {
        free(av->argv);
        free(av->argb);
        av->argv = 0;
        av->argb = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char   *buffer = 0;
    size_t  buflen = 0;
    ssize_t length;

    while ((length = getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin)) > 0)
    {
        buffer[--length] = '\0';
        ArgVector av = make_argv(buffer);
        printf("line [%s]\n", buffer);
        printf("argc %zu\n", av.argc);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < av.argc; i++)
             printf("%zu = [%s]\n", i, av.argv[i]);
        free_argv(&av);
    }
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The `ArgVector` structure encapsulates the key information — the vector of pointers to strings (`argv`), the base (start) of the copy of the input string (`argb`), and the number of arguments (`argc`).  The elements of `argv` point into the string recorded by `argb`.

The function `free_argv()` releases allocated memory and makes the structure safe for reuse.  The function `make_argv()` makes a conservative estimate of how many space-separated arguments there could be.  If the input string is a single letter, there is one argument and the length calculation for `calloc()` gives the value `2` (allowing for the null terminator).  If there are two letters separated by a space, the length calculation gives the value `3`, and so on.  This is the maximum number of arguments there can be; if the string is 30 letters with no spacing, then it will over-allocate the `argv` array.  It would be possible to `realloc()` the array to the correct size, but there is limited benefit to doing that unless the over-allocation is egregiously wrong — say, more than 128 bytes (or 16 too many arguments).  You'd then need to capture the number of entries in the `argv` array, which is easily done, but the current code doesn't do it.  The code checks that the memory allocation succeeded and if there's a problem, resets the structure.  It could actually call `free_argv()` to do that reset — it probably should, in fact.

Assuming that the necessary memory was allocated, the main loop scans over the copy of the string, skipping white space, then setting the next argument pointer, then finding the end of the argument, and repeating.

When that's done, it returns the structure.

The main program uses POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the input because it makes life so easy.  The code should check that the last character read was a newline before zapping it.  It would be possible to use `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';` to avoid zapping the last character of a file that did not end with a newline.

The code does assume that `calloc()` sets the pointers to null — that's the case on the vast majority of CPUs, and you're unlikely to come across a system where that's a problem (but there used to be systems where it could be a problem, once upon a quarter century or more ago).

Sample run:

```
  a  b  c
line [  a  b  c]
argc 3
0 = [a]
1 = [b]
2 = [c]
abc def  ghi jkl   
line [abc def  ghi jkl   ]
argc 4
0 = [abc]
1 = [def]
2 = [ghi]
3 = [jkl]

line []
argc 0
    
line [    ]
argc 0
    dddd     eeeee    zzzzz      
line [    dddd     eeeee    zzzzz      ]
argc 3
0 = [dddd]
1 = [eeeee]
2 = [zzzzz]
[ a = b + c ]
line [[ a = b + c ]]
argc 7
0 = [[]
1 = [a]
2 = [=]
3 = [b]
4 = [+]
5 = [c]
6 = []]
```

This gives you a solid basis to adapt to suit your requirements.  Note that you need to track both `argv` and the `argb` in some way.  This mechanism gives you a structure that is self-contained.  In the code in the question, if it is permissible to zap the `buf` string, then you could use that instead of making a copy.  The `argc` element is optional but convenient; the null pointer at the end of `argv` also reliably tells you how many arguments there are.

The parsing code can be made more complex to recognize quoted strings and backslash escapes and other notations — splitting on white space alone is fairly simplistic.

The functions are made `static` because they aren't accessed outside this source file.  If they were going to be accessed outside the file, there'd be a header defining the structure type and the two function signatures — and both the file defining the functions and the files using the functions would include that header to gain access to the relevant information, and the functions would no longer be `static`, of course.